# Where does one proofread edits?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Where do I find edits to proofread? I would like to proofread edits submitted by other people. I'm not sure whether or not it's limited by reputation.

Comment: Do you know where the review queue is?

Comment: (It's up to your right, in the blue bar)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Not with 65 rep, I think.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edits suggested by users having less than 2000 reputation are reviewed in the *Suggested Edits Review Queue*, which can be found at [this location](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits).

However, before you can start reviewing here, you will have to earn the associated privilege. As can be read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), you need 2000 reputation to start doing this.

So while having less than 2000 rep, you suggest edits, and after that, you can edit immediately, and review others' suggestions.